# pip install local package to target directory

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pip

I have a Python library that is published to PyPI. Before pushing each new version of the library, I want to test it by upgrading a sample application to use the new version.

The [suggested method](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/#working-in-development-mode) to do this is to work in "development mode" using the `-e` (`--editable`) flag:

```
$ pip install -e <my package root>
```

And this does indeed install the package into my global environment.

However, my sample program is written for Google App Engine, which requires that [all third-party libraries be copied](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27) into an application-specific folder (`./lib` in my case). I normally install packages here by using the `-t` (`--target`) option to pip:

```
$ pip install -t lib/ <package>
```

However, it appears that the `-e` and `-t` options [are](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4390) [not](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/562) [compatible](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3246), and my attempts to install my local, unpublished library to a specified target folder by using both flags together fail.

How can I test my library package by installing it in a custom directory before publishing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For one-time testing of a new package, installing directly from the local filesystem seems to be the best bet:

```
$ cd /my/sample/application
$ pip install -t lib /my/local/package
```

This install won't stay in sync as I make further changes to the local package (as it would if I were to use `pip install --editable`), but I can live without that for this use case.

I couldn't get [@pbaranay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47562976/925478) to work because of the way `pip install -e` uses "egg-info" files that apparently are not understood/traversed by GAE's dev_appserver.py script. The suggestion to create a virtualenv and symlink it to lib (rather than installing packages directly to lib with `-t`) is a good one, though.

Comment: Smh, this works for me. I am unable to make it run using the --target or --find-links. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Adapting the instructions from Jeffrey Godwyll's [Google App Engine Vendoring Done Right](https://jeffgodwyll.com/posts/2015/google-appegine-vendoring-done-right/) worked for me:

```
cd ~/app-engine-project-directory
mkdir lib
ln -s env/lib/python2.7/site-packages lib
pip install -e ../my-local-dependency
```

(Of course, you may need to change the third line depending on which version of Python you're using.)

Comment: Yes, this is a nice way to manage the dependencies. I think the `mkdir lib` line is incorrect, though; if the directory already exists, then `ln -s` will link `lib/site-packages -> env/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, which is not quite what we want.

Comment: Unfortunately, `pip install -e` creates an "egg-info" file (poor man's symlink) in the site-packages folder, and the GAE `dev_appserver.py` script apparently can't follow it. In any case, the application is not able to see the local dependency when run with dev_appserver.py.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this approach: you'd be uploading **all** your local installation packages together with your app, meaning you could exceed your app file quota and/or your could upload libraries that may conflict with the sandbox, causing obscure problems with your app when deployed.

Comment: @DanCornilescu This solution assumes (based on the linked source and the relative path to `env/lib...`) that one is using a project-specific virtualenv. Assuming you've only installed libraries actually needed by your project into this virtualenv, why would it be any worse than installing them directly to `lib`? (although I do see that a fresh virtualenv installs pip, setuptools, and wheel by default, so perhaps that is what you are getting at...)

Comment: You install into `lib` only what you absolutely need for your app - not everything from your local/virtenv installation.

Answer (score 1):

You could install with `-e` your package into your local python installation or wherever you desire, then symlink that particular local package dir into your app's `lib` dir:

```
ln -s /my/local/package /my/sample/application/lib/
```

Comment: Using `-e` seems to only create an "egg-info" file in the `site-packages` dir, it doesn't actually install the whole package (apparently). So, it doesn't seem like there's any package to which I can symlink?

Comment: Then I guess I misunderstood your intended `-e` usage, I though you get both. You *might* not be able to use such library with GAE (but I'm not sure, never tried to use eggs in GAE).